# Reporting services printing crashes IE

Tags: internet-explorer, reporting-services, internet-explorer-10

We have been using SSRS 2008 R2 for over a year and printing has worked fine. As the client browsers on Windows 7 are upgraded to IE10 we have some browsers crash when the users click on the print icon. The faulting module is **rsclientprint64.dll**

To try to resolve this issue I manually copied the dll and associated files to C:\Windows\Downloaded Program Files and registered the dll using regsvr32.
I registered the rsclientprint64.dll instead of the rsclientprint.dll since that is the file that ssrs downloads in our case. I did try to register the 32 bit version too but still no success.

I added the url for the report server to trusted sites and set the security to allow downloaded signed activex controls. It does download them but ie still crashes.

Does anyone have other ideas?

Comment: I think the issue is that when you use a 64bit browser then the rsclientprint64.dll gets downloaded and if using a 32bit browser then you get the rsclientprint.dll. So far we can only print using the 32 bit dll from a 32bit browser. I want to get the 64 bit version of this dll to work with ssrs. We are running the RTM version of SQL so do you think installing SP2 will fix the issue?

Comment: OT I know but I am so over hitting problems and reading about others hitting problems with 32bit vs 64bit.  Microsoft have made a mess of this IMO.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Let me guess, you are running SQL Server R2 without SP2. I had to upgrade to SQL Server 2008 R2 SERVICE PACK 2.

> The version of RsClientPrint you get with R2/SP2 is 10.50.4000, while
>   the RTM version I had was 10.50.1600.

To see what version of SQL server you have, run `Select @@version` as a query in SSMS.

You can read more here.
[ReportViewer's Print Button Incompatible with IE 10?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17031060/reportviewers-print-button-incompatible-with-ie-10)

Answer (score 2):

**Resolution to fix IE11 from crashing**

If you get the RSClientPrint.cab from a 2008 R2 "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\MSRS10.GENERAL\Reporting Services\ReportServer\bin" and extract it to your desired client machine. Use these files to either create your own bat file and run it or just copy them to your "C:\windows\Downloaded Program Files".

Once your files are copied to "C:\windows\Downloaded Program Files" You will need to register your .dll: In CMD type - `regsvr32 "c:\Windows\Downloaded Program Files\RSClientPrint.dll"`

Issue 1: "C:\windows\Downloaded Program Files" is usually locked

Resolution: In CMD type - `attrib "C:\windows\Downloaded Program Files" -S`

Issue 2: Error message found when registering your dll file

Resolution: Run CMD as Admin

Bat file to run locally

```
 @echo off

    set srcpath= c:\pathname

    attrib "C:\windows\Downloaded Program Files" -S

    xcopy %srcpath%\*.* "c:\Windows\Downloaded Program Files" /Y

    regsvr32 "c:\Windows\Downloaded Program Files\RSClientPrint.dll"
```

From a server to a client machine:

```
@echo off


attrib "C:\windows\Downloaded Program Files" -S

robocopy "\\dc01\packages\rsclientprint" "c:\Windows\Downloaded Program Files"

regsvr32 "c:\Windows\Downloaded Program Files\RSClientPrint.dll"
```

Comment: Note that using regsvr32 will run the dll from the location you specify (it does not necessarily have to run from "C:\Windows\Downloaded Program Files") and you need the ".rll" files to be in the same location as the ".dll" file or you will get an error something like "resource cannot be found".

Answer (score 0):

This is an general IE10 issue that affects both x32 and x64 versions when trying to print a PDF document from the browser.

A workaround is to open Adobe Reader or Acrobat (whichever is your default), go to Edit > Preferences > Internet, and uncheck "Display PDF in Browser".

Internet PDFs will now open by default in Adobe instead of the screwed up IE10.

Answer (score 0):

Try running internet explorer as Administrator
or
Add your report server url to internet explorer Trusted sites.