# Unable to load client print control in report view

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, reportingservices-2005

I have developed report using SSRS 2005 and deployed in server.
Server : Windows Server 2008 R2.
SQL : SQL Server 2005
When I click on print button of report it shows Unable to load Client Print Control. It Work in IE8. We are trying in IE11

I have tried following things : 
Extracted the files from RSClientPrint.cab from Report server and put it in C:\Windows\Downloaded ProgramFiles and then register the dll. Also I have copied all those files in C:\Windows\System32 and registered the same.

Also installed SQL Server Service Pack Update and ReportViewer Service Pack Update

Still I am getting the same error in Server as well as client machine.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I bet this is do with Security Settings for downloading/scripting controls etc in Internet Explorer. I'm fairly sure that IE later than v8 changed the defaults.

Do you remember getting a prompt the first time you used the report in IE8?

Try adding your site to the Trusted Sites list.

**EDIT**

My updated suggestion is to install [Microsoft Report Viewer 2015 Runtime](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=45496).

Comment: I have tried to add application in Trusted Sites List but no luck. IE closes in a moment rather than open application

Comment: Hi Suman. Is that behaviour different to what it did before adding to the Trusted Sites list?

Comment: Just done a quick search of web, found a couple of articles, including 2 StackOverflow both suggesting that ReportViewer component supplied with any SQL Server version < 2008 R2 IS NOT compatible with IE10 and above...

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15550384/reporting-services-printing-crashes-ie

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17031060/reportviewers-print-button-incompatible-with-ie-10

Comment: Both solutions talk about upgrading to SQL Server 2008 R2. You said you have extracted the component CAB from the ReportServer (2005) - I'm not sure what would happen if you took the version of ReportViewer from SQL Server 2008 R2 and manually installed that on your test machine...